# Sorting using custom value system in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have an application that dynamically creates a drop-down menu based on certain values in the database. Often the drop-down values are just in the order they come up but I would like to put them in a certain order.

An example of my value system:

```
Newbie = 0
Amateur = 1
Skilled = 2
Pro = 3
GrandMaster = 4
```

How would I take the data above and use it to sort an array full of those values (Newbie etc). I've thought about creating a hash of the values but even then I still am not sure how to apply that to the `sort` method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code have you written? We can help you more seeing, and suggesting corrections, than if we write it all from scratch for you. Plus, on Stack Overflow, we expect you to have written code, and then tell us why it didn't work.

Comment: You're right. This would have helped out my poorly explained question. I'll try to do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my poorly explained question the others trying to answer my question didn't really get a chance but using their help I did manage to figure out my problem.

```
ex_array = ["GrandMaster", "Newbie", "Pro", "Skilled", "Amateur"] 
value_sys = {:Newbie=>0, :Amateur=>1, :Skilled=>2, :Pro=>3, :GrandMaster=>4}

ex_array.sort { |a,b| value_sys[a.to_sym] <=> value_sys[b.to_sym]
=> ["Newbie", "Amateur", "Skilled","Pro", "GrandMaster"]
```

Thanks for the help guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort this array just by using the usual sorting the sorting won't be done by name it will be done by value. and if these are not integer objects and are some user defined class then sorting based on a particular attribute can be achieved very efficiently by

```
lst.sort_by &:first
```

where first is the attribute of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Sort has by value:

```
hash = {:Newbie=>0, :Amateur=>1, :Skilled=>2, :Pro=>3}
> hash.sort { hash{a} <=> hash{b} }
=> [[:Newbie, 0], [:Amateur, 1], [:Skilled, 2], [:Pro, 3]]
```

Or use Ruby Hash#sort_by method:

```
hash.sort_by { |k,v| v }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `Level` model that has a `sort_id` identifying the displayed order and a `name` holding the displayed name. I recommend using `default_scope` to set the default order for that model because it is likely that you always want to sort `Level` records this way:

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  #### attributes
  # id (integer)
  # name (string)
  # sort_id (integer)

  default_scope order('sort_id ASC')

  # rest of model...
end
```

Then, the only thing you have to do in your view to display a picklist is

```
<%= f.select("level", Level.pluck(:name)) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to @padde.  I prefer to avoid default scopes.

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  #### attributes
  # id (integer)
  # name (string)
  # value (integer)
end
```

In the view

```
<%= f.select("level", Level.order(:value).map{|l| [l.name, l.value] } %>
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Parse your value system for further use:

   ```
   values = <<EOF
   Newbie = 0
   Amateur = 1
   Skilled = 2
   Pro = 3
   GrandMaster = 4
   EOF

   value_map = Hash[values.split("\n").map{|v| v.split(/\s*=\s*/)}.map{|v| [v[0], v[1].to_i]}]
   #=> {"Newbie"=>0, "Amateur"=>1, "Skilled"=>2, "Pro"=>3, "GrandMaster"=>4}
   ```
2. Assign the array values a weight according to `value_map` to transform the array into a new one, sort according to the weight, and then transform the new array back.

   ```
   # here I created a sample array
   array = value_map.keys.shuffle
   #=> ["Newbie", "Pro", "Skilled", "Amateur", "GrandMaster"]

   # transform and sort
   sorted = array.map{|v| [v, value_map[v] || 0xFFFF]}.sort_by{|v| v[1]}.map{|v| v[0]}
   #=> ["Newbie", "Amateur", "Skilled", "Pro", "GrandMaster"]
   ```

   Or you can bypass the transform step and just use the `sort_by` method:

   ```
   sorted = array.sort_by{|v| value_map[v] || 0xFFFF}
   ```

Comment: It's OK to down vote, however, comment your reason to let me know what's wrong with my answer!

Comment: You understood my question the best, if that helps.